# Origin <origin> is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, google-chrome, cors

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/test. Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I read about cross domain ajax requests, and understand the underlying security issue. In my case, 2 servers are running locally, and like to enable cross domain requests during testing.

```
localhost:8080 - Google Appengine dev server
localhost:3000 - Node.js server
```

I am issuing an ajax request to `localhost:8080 - GAE server` while my page is loaded from node server. What is the easiest, and safest ( Don't want to start chrome with `disable-web-security` option). If I have to change `'Content-Type'`, should I do it at node server? How?

Comment: A faster solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21622564/4455570

Answer (score 285, accepted):

Since they are running on different ports, they are different JavaScript `origin`.  It doesn't matter that they are on the same machine/hostname.

You need to enable CORS on the server (localhost:8080).  Check out this site: http://enable-cors.org/

All you need to do is add an HTTP header to the server:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
```

Or, for simplicity:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Thought don't use "*" if your server is trying to set cookie and you use `withCredentials = true`

> when responding to a credentialed request, server must specify a domain, and cannot use wild carding.

[You can read more about `withCredentials` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: if we want to add this header into an HTML then what should we do for it?

Comment: I didn't think that port was necessary but if you're using a non-standard port such as 3000 you have to include it in the CORS policy.

Comment: Note that from testing we just did at my office, all parts of that header are required: `localhost` isn't enough on its own, and as Michael pointed out, port is required if you're not using a standard port.

Comment: Thanks for this response.  Just wanna highlight the security implications of using '*' as the value here.  This allows all origins:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Seems like the first example would be best in terms of least access.  Details about how to do this with multiple domains here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1850482/1566623

Comment: For clarity's sake, when it is said that you need to "add an HTTP header to the server", this means that the given `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header needs to be an added header to HTTP responses that the server sends. This header needs to be part of the **server's response, it does not need to be part of the client's request**. Specifically what happens is before the client makes the actual request you want, the browser sends an `OPTIONS` request before it, and if the server's response to that `OPTIONS` request does not contain the header, the browser will not send your desired request.

Comment: It is important to read the relevant tips for your backend servers at enable-cors.org.

Comment: Are there any risks in allowing anyone access using `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`?

Comment: @Percy: that depends, is your data sensitive?  Setting a wildcard value is effectively turning CORS protections off completely for the resource in question.  Understanding the motivations behind having CORS in the first place is important, but far too deep a topic for a single SO comment.

Answer (score 85):

If you need a quick work around in Chrome for ajax requests, this chrome plugin automatically allows you to access any site from any source by adding the proper response header

[Chrome Extension Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en)

Comment: I don't know why you're not getting more upvotes. This is the least intrusive for development on localhost with Chrome.

Comment: definitely agree. Easy to enable for localhost dev against a remote server without having to change the config for the remote server.

Comment: @DavidBetz: considering you verify the extension and trust it, of course ;)

Comment: THIS SHOULD BE THE TOP ANSWER! Especially where localhost is concerned.

Comment: This has to be the top answer ! It worked with a single click. If you're developing some app on Localhost, USE THIS!

Comment: If this was a good solution, CORS would not have been invented in the first place.
Applying this header to any host disable the CORS protection and exposes you to malicious scripts, not just yours. Don't be surprised if your bank account is suddenly empty.

Comment: This extension is not available on chrome store

Comment: Thanks Ashish, looks like the old plugin was removed. I updated the link. This new plugin gives you more CORS control

Comment: @dolmen You just reminded us of the possible threat. Disabled the CORS extension and removed it too. Never gonna try it again, unless I'm on a virtual machine or an offline environment.

Answer (score 67):

You have to enable CORS to solve this

#### if your app is created with simple node.js

set it in your response headers like

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
});
response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000);
```

#### if your app is created with express framework

use a CORS middleware like

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
}
```

and apply via

```
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(allowCrossDomain);
    //some other code
});
```

Here are two reference links

1. [how-to-allow-cors-in-express-nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors-in-express-nodejs#answer-7069902)
2. [diving-into-node-js-very-first-app](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/11/19/diving-into-node-js-very-first-app/) #see the Ajax section

Comment: can you please specify, how to use `config.allowedDomains` . say in my case what uri should I put there?

Comment: @bsr : you can use `*` or the `specific domain` you want to give access to.

Comment: so am I the only one getting `app.configure()` is not a function error?

Comment: @PrameshBajrachaya I didn't include the "app.configure" part -- only "app.use(allowCrossDomain)", and it worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

In router.js just add code before calling get/post methods. It works for me without errors.

```
//Importing modules @Brahmmeswar
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Contact = require('../models/contacts');

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });
```

Comment: Saved a lot of my time. I knew how to fix the CORS issue earlier, but it does not worth remembering it. This solution works without any change. Thanks

Comment: Update: this does not allow DELETE call yet.

Answer (score 9):

I accept @Rocket hazmat's answer as it lead me to the solution. It was indeed on the GAE server I needed to set the header. I had to set these

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "*"
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" -> "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
```

setting only `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"`  gave error

```
Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

Also, if auth token needs to be sent, add this too

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" -> "true"
```

Also, at client, set `withCredentials`

this causes 2 requests to sent to the server, one with `OPTIONS`. Auth cookie is not send with it, hence need to treat outside auth.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using express, you can use cors middleware as follows:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

Comment: You can and you should. Here are more options and documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Answer (score 5):

I was facing a problem while calling cross origin resource using ajax from chrome.

I have used node js and local http server to deploy my node js app.

I was getting error response, when I access cross origin resource

I found one solution on that ,

1) I have added below code to my app.js file

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
```

2) In my html page called cross origin resource using `$.getJSON();`

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/users", function (data) {
    alert("*******Success*********");
    var response=JSON.stringify(data);
    alert("success="+response);
    document.getElementById("employeeDetails").value=response;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your NodeJS Server below imports:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you got 403 after that please reduce filters in WEB.XML tomcat config to the following:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone searching for the solution , if you are using express here is the quick solution .

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
```

1) install cors using npm `npm install cors --save`

2) import it [require ] `const cors = require('cors')`

3) use it as middleware  `app.use(cors())`

for details [insatll and usage of cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) .
That is it, hopefully it works.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got the answer for apache Tomcat8

You have to edit the tomcat web.xml file.

probabily it will be inside webapps folder,

```
sudo gedit /opt/tomcat/webapps/your_directory/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

find it and edit it

```
<web-app>


<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>10</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>


<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>



</web-app>
```

This will allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin all hosts.
If you need to change it from all hosts to only your host you can edit the

```
<param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
<param-value>http://localhost:3000</param-value>
```

above code from * to your http://your_public_IP or http://www.example.com

you can refer here [Tomcat filter documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter/Filter_Class_Name)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
next();});
```

add this to your routes which you are calling from front-end.
Ex-
if you call for **http://localhost:3000/users/register** you must add this code fragment on your back-end .js file which this route lays.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP, use this to set headers.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi This is the way to solve CORS problem in node Just add these lines on server "api" side in Node.js(or what ever your server File),
befor that make sure to install "cors"

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    app.use(express.json());
    var cors = require('cors');
    app.use(cors());
```

Answer (score 1):

If your server is `server=express()` just add `server.use(cors())` to next line. For Example:

`server.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
server=express()
server.use(cors())

server.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send({"name":"aakash","name2":"aakash4dev"})
})
server.listen(3000)
```

`index.html`

```
<script>
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/')
  .then(res=> res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
</script>
```

[image: Access-Control-Allow-Origin]

Answer (score 0):

use dataType: 'jsonp', works for me.

```
   async function get_ajax_data(){

       var _reprojected_lat_lng = await $.ajax({

                                type: 'GET',

                                dataType: 'jsonp',

                                data: {},

                                url: _reprojection_url,

                                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                                    console.log(jqXHR)

                                },

                                success: function (data) {

                                    console.log(data);



                                    // note: data is already json type, you just specify dataType: jsonp

                                    return data;

                                }

                            });





 } // function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express,

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
app.use(cors())
```

If you are using `app.use(express.json());` code line in your server file to parse incoming requests with JSON payloads and is based on body-parser, keep in mind to use it after using  `app.use(cors())` code line. Otherwise, security issues may occur.
[CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and I followed all the recommended snippets both for php side (setting the headers) and on react (axios withCredenitial=true), and I couldn't get rid of the error.

In php I had:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Finally I noticed that these headers do not appear in the response.

The response should look like this:

[image]

Apparently, my vscode started saving the file as UTF8-BOM for some reason. As a result, headers were sent immediately, and all subsequent header(..) statement were ignored because `headers were already sent`.

Two useful php commands to check this issue: [headers_list()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php) and [headers_sent()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php)

Notepad++ is good to view file encoding, and switching to a different encoding:

[image]

Comment: From your script my problem has been solved, when I added third line of code: header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

Answer (score 0):

While I found Brahmmeswara Rao Palepu's answer works great, it does not work for all HTTP Verbs by default.

I was getting the below error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/users/user/159' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.`

To allow DELETE Verb too, I had to explicitly add another header `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` in the express's router`(routes/index.js)`file.

```
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
  next();
});
```

Hope this will be helpful to someone who do not want to learn much about CORS and directly bypass the error for local development.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error :
just install cors.

1. npm i cors
   and use like this:
2. const cors = require('cors');
3. app.use(cors());

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).