# Access Control allow origin

Tags: apache, backbone.js

Not sure what exactly is the issue - I have web app on apache with Marionette backbone models connecting to server side on different port.I Tried below to allow the access but doesn't not see to work:

This is under Directory tag of httpd.conf

```
   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin  "*"
    </IfModule>


Header module is loaded as ./apachectl -M results below
 Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 mpm_worker_module (static)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18643661/566092

Comment: This didn't help. I setup as below :  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin  "*"
         Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
         Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
</IfModule> but same error.