# Incoming video issue in WebRTC

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

I'm trying first time to run video conference script WebRTC, the issue is that can't get the incoming video. You're can see http://wdd.co.il:1234

What I did:

1) Installed the node.js on debian 8 with commands that mentioned [her](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager):

```
apt-get install curl
curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | bash -
apt-get install --yes nodejs
apt-get install --yes build-essential
```

2) Installed following in the script folder:

```
npm install socket.io
npm install node-static
```

3) Run The server:

```
node server.js
```

After all that, nothing changed, steel not see the incoming video in client browser(firefix,chrome,opera).

I am almost certain that I'm missing something, asking for yours help to understand.

The files, [server.js](http://wdd.co.il/chat/server.js), [index.html](http://wdd.co.il/chat/index.html).

Comment: Please look in web console and include error messages in questions like this. I get CORS errors from your link, [likely from the port number](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18643011/918910).

Comment: I added Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" into .htaccess and enabled module header, but without results.

Comment: How can i find error messages? maybe you mean error in debug [link](http://wdd.co.il/webrtc_internals_dump.txt)

Comment: No I mean the JavaScript console in the browser.

Comment: Here is http://wdd.co.il/wdd.co.il-1439711319454.log

Comment: Yes, those are the CORS errors: "cannot load http://wdd.co.il/socket.io ...` No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://wdd.co.il:1234' is therefore not allowed access." - Essentially `http://wdd.co.il` and `http://wdd.co.il:1234` are different origins.

Comment: Strangely, the 'Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"' in .htaccess not working.