# How to upload excel file on server(django) in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I want to upload file on server, but in Utility Service there is variable **files** in for loop is undefined during debug, please check directive is correct or not.

**HTML**

```
 <input type="file" accept=".xlsx" file-model/>
 <button ng-click="upload()">upload me</button>
```

**fileModel directive**

```
app.directive('fileModel', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        link: function($scope, $element) {
          var fileInput = $element.find('input[type="file"]');
          fileInput.bind('change', function(e) {               
            $scope.notReady = e.target.files.length == 0;
            $scope.files = [];
            for (var i in e.target.files) {
              if (typeof e.target.files[i] == 'object')       
                  $scope.files.push(e.target.files[i]);
            }
          });
        }
    };
  });
```

**Controller**

```
 $scope.upload = function() {        
      var uploadUrl =  'someurl';
      UtilityService.upload($scope.files, $scope.user, uploadUrl);
  };
```

**Service**

```
function UtilityService($http, $rootScope) {

      var service = {};
      service.upload=upload;

      function upload(files, user, uploadUrl) {
      var formData = new FormData();
      for (var i in files) {
        formData.append('file_' + i, files[i]);
      }

      formData.append("UserId", user.id);
      formData.append("UserRole", user.roles);

      $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: config.server +uploadUrl,
          enctype: "multipart/form-data",
          data: formData,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined,
          },
          transformRequest: angular.identity
        })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          service.data = data;

        });
    }
    return service;
  }
```

Comment: You actually have 2 problems. 1 being that CORS is stopping the request, and 2 being that your server is responding with a 500. For your first issue, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642828/origin-http-localhost3000-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin.

Comment: Since, your ports differ, your browser is respecting the Cross origin policy, which it should.

Comment: Try running Chrome with the flag **--disable-web-security** which should help you get rid of the Cross origin issue. However, you should set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to * later.

Comment: @kensplanet thanks for reply, I edited question please check it. During debug files is undefined..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess the issue is with this line - **var fileInput = $element.find('input[type="file"]');**

Not sure why you need to find anything. $element is the actual file input element here.

**Modified directive - try this**

```
app.directive('fileModel', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        link: function($scope, $element) {
          var fileInput = $element;
          fileInput.bind('change', function(e) {               
            $scope.notReady = e.target.files.length == 0;
            $scope.files = [];
            for (var i in e.target.files) {
              if (typeof e.target.files[i] == 'object')       
                  $scope.files.push(e.target.files[i]);
            }
          });
        }
    };
  });
```