# Send ajax request to remote node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, cors

I had simple nodejs server(CORS included) :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = 8001;
http.listen(port,function () {
    console.log('listening on:'+ port);
});
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8000');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
app.post('/getSockets', function (req,res,next) {
   console.log(req.body);
});
```

and simple ajax request

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8001/getSockets",
                data: "Hello world",
                success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log("success!");
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(XMLHttpRequest.status);
                }
            });
```

But i had an error 404 that localhost:8001/getSockets not found

Comment: try `var http = require('http').createServer(app);' in node js server code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 404 error means the URL doesn't exist or it can't access it

change this line:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8000');
```

to this:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8001');
```

Comment: ty so much its help

Answer (score 1):

You are only allowing ajax requests to access resource on port `8000` you should change it to `8001` or just not specify a port.

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8000');
```

Also please see  [using CORS with ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642828/origin-http-localhost3000-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)