# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cors

I have a simple `spring boot` service running in a `docker` container exposed on port `8080` that is calling a `mysql` database.

When I hit `localhost:8080/blogs`, I get back `[{"author":"Christopher Bolton","title":"Test Title 1","content":"This is some content","date":"2017-08-29"}]`

This is working just fine when I hit it directly in the browser. However, when I try it from `jQuery` I am getting the normal `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Here is my spring boot service:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ChrisboltonServiceApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ChrisboltonServiceApplication.class, args);
}

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(path="/blogs")
public @ResponseBody Iterable<ChrisBolton> getAllUsers() {
    List<ChrisBolton> result = jdbcTemplate.query(
            "SELECT * FROM blog",
            (rs, rowNum) -> new ChrisBolton(rs.getString("author"), 
                                               rs.getString("title"), 
                                               rs.getString("content"), 
                                               rs.getDate("date"))
    );

    return result;
}
}
```

Here is my `jQuery`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:8080/blogs",
  crossDomain: true
}).done(function(data) {

  console.log(data);
});
```

But I am still getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/blogs. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have tried [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) by adding the `@CrossOrigin` to the `getAllUsers()` method and I have tried at the class level. I have also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642828/origin-http-localhost3000-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin) because I am running my UI on port `3000`. But that link is not spring specific.

***EDIT***

Adding my request headers:

```
GET /blogs HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 
Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Response in network tab (Chrome):

`[{"author":"Christopher Bolton","title":"Test Title 1","content":"This is some content","date":"2017-08-29"}]`

So it looks like I am getting data back in the network tab. However, my `console.log(data)` produces the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try adding this to your application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ChrisboltonServiceApplication {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }

...
```

Also, try removing the `crossDomain: true` from the `$.ajax()`.

Comment: do i still keep `@CrossOrigin`? Still getting same error.

Comment: also, i added above the fact that i am using docker and exposing port 8080.  Maybe this could be part of the issue?

Comment: Actually, everything should have been working with `@CrossOrigin` alone. I just tested here and it works fine. The fact that you use a docker container should be affecting it. What image is your container based? Isn't there some kind of proxy in front of the spring boot inside the container?

Comment: The container is running on my machine and the spring boot app is exposed on port `8080`. My UI is running on port `3000`. So it's `localhost` calling `localhost` on different ports. Is there some proxy concept I am missing here?

Comment: No. I meant if the container had a proxy (like nginx) in front of the spring boot app. But it seems unlikely. Do you see the CORS headers in the response at the network tab when you request and get an error?

Comment: So in the network tab I am actually getting the data back from the server. So now I am even more confused on why I am getting this error in the console.

Comment: Not the data, but the CORS headers, are they present?

Comment: No I do not see the CORS in the response.

Comment: Maybe your spring boot application is not reloading, not recompiling and applying the CORS-addition changes. Can you show us how you build your project? The `Dockerfile`, maybe?

Comment: Okay, i wiped all my images and stopped containers... Then I did my normal `mvn clean install` and `docker build -t chrisbolton-service .` My guess is that it wasn't picking up the changes because i wasn't tagging it?

Comment: Unlikely. Did the problem go away? Other changes (create a controller that returns a string) get picked up? If so, this theory does not hold

Comment: Yeah, it did work. Getting the response back as expected now. Didn't change anything just wiped all my containers and rebuilt my image from scratch. I was rebuilding my jar and importing it into my container every time. Not 100% what was happening. But docker was the issue.

Answer (score 5):

*JUST ADD DevConfiguration  in any  package then update application.properties file*

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@Profile("development")
public class DevConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
 
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS").allowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

> Update application.properties file

```
# application.properties
spring.profiles.active=development
server.port=8090
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:8080")` to proper method if you want `:8080` to allow request there. It's a simple config for one endpoint/controller. You can use variable there too for customization later of course.

Comment: I know that you're technically right, but that is bad advice. People see one off configurations and apply them to the N places they are applicable in their code.