# angular 4 post request not working, but postman is able to send post request to spring boot server?

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cross-domain, postman

I am able to successfully send a post request to my restcontroller in spring boot using postman.
[image]

The restcontroller is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/performaction",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public void performReboot(@RequestBody PerformAction performAction) {
         System.out.println("......rebooting blade to performRebootservice...........for blade id :: : ::"+performAction.getBladeId() +performAction.getActionName());

 ..........
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

However I am not able to send this post request from my angular, the request is as follows:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json");

    return this.http.post(this.performactionUrl, {"bladeId" : 2,"actionName" : "reboot"},{headers});
```

Note: I have added the WebMvcConfigurer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065156/access-control-allow-origin-with-spring-boot?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa)!

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you send request from angular? What error it shows?

Comment: if any ans is helpful the plz try to do upvote and if answer is right then mark as accepted coz other dev can see that ans first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using `subscribe` method your api is never called. Just use subscription method in your component.

Answer (score 0):

```
return this.http.post(this.performactionUrl, {"bladeId" : 2,"actionName" : "reboot"},{headers});
```

should be -

```
return this.http.post(this.performactionUrl, JSON.stringify({"bladeId" : 2,"actionName" : "reboot"}),headers);
```