# CORS with React, Webpack and Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, cors, axios

How to set up CORS Header in react front end app with webpack and axios.

I want to get a response from an API url. Do I have to set up sepparate server with let's say express, or it can be done with webpack-dev-server from the front-end application.

I get the error:

```
Failed to load https://api.test.io/test/res: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642828/origin-http-localhost3000-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: It seems like you need to whitelist localhost for development with your API provider https://test.io

Comment: I opened <https://api.test.io/test/res> in the browser and it says 404. Sometimes if you use API in a wrong way, you will get a CORS response.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with the server, not with Axios. You need to setup your webpack devServer headers to allow CORS.

```
devServer: {
   headers: { 
       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
       "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't set **CORS** headers client side, they are sent automatically by the browser. You do it server side. Configure Webpack server to reply with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set to the wildcard `*`.

```
devServer: {
   headers: { 
       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
   }
}
```