# Failed To Fetch error when trying to fetch from my API

Tags: json

I am extremely new to NodeJS and ReactJS coding so please bare with me, here is the code.

```
function App() {
  return <div className='app'>
    <button onClick={() => {
      fetch('http://localhost:8080/bitcoin')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(console.log);
    }}>Display Data
    </button>
  </div>
}
```

My ReactJS website is trying to access my backend API, but I am getting a

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

error

Comment: Do you get a valid JSON output when visiting http://localhost:8080/bitcoin in, for example, a browser?

Comment: I do yes, my API works perfectly by itself, it just cant seem to access it via my ReactJS website

Comment: Is your react site running from `:8080` as well ? Otherwise it might be a CORS problem

Comment: It is actually a CORS problem, not much knowledge on that problem. My API is on port 8080, and my react site is on 3000

Comment: @AlexGottschalk check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642828/origin-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I have looked into this, I'm just not sure where to put "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", they say in header, but I'm not sure where that is

Comment: It should go on your API code, the one serving the data. Can you post some info about your API code ? What technonology you use ? Node.js + express ?

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot about this after I fixed it lol, thanks for your help man

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642828/origin-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin Did this