# How to fix CORS error "http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in a react-app?

Tags: reactjs, cors, fetch, use-effect, access-control

I did find a solution approach to this for express servers, but I am not able to implement the same to my react-app.

referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642828/origin-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin). Please suggest. (I am beginner to CORS)

Here is my App.js file:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {

  const APP_ID = "--"
  const APP_KEY = "--"

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    getRecipes();
  }, [])

  const getRecipes = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}&from=0&to=3&calories=591-722&health=alcohol-free`);
    const data = response.json();
    console.log(data);
  }

  return <div className="App">
    <form className="search-form">
      <input className="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Search query here!" />
      <button
        className="search-button" type="submit">
        Search
      </button>
    </form>
    <h1 onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>{counter}</h1>
  </div>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The problem should be with your server. Try adding `app.use(express.json());` and then try to see if you can fetch that request. app would be your express server instance variable

Comment: that is the thing, I do not have an express server for this I have used create-react-app.

Comment: If you do not have a express server then probably you need to proxy that request you can google it out. Generally, CORS should be handled on server side. though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For production and almost all use cases, this needs to be done on a server (i.e the backend you are using, usually running node.js, not the frontend on react).

However, create-react-app does let you set a proxy on the client-side to test during development, albeit it is not recommended, since if you forget to remove it when pushing your code out to production, its can be a serious security issue. If its just a learning project you can do this:

If this is your API: `http://123.4.345.53:7000/api/profile/`
add this part in your `package.json` file: `"proxy": "http://123.4.345.53:7000/"`
Then you can do the following:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
axios
    .get('api/profile/')
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }); 
});
```

If you decide to use a dedicated backend, and it runs node.js, this is done like so:

```
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```